# Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

For some strange reason I get a weird error.

I have an element (which I'd defined with PHP) that eventuly looks like this:

```
    <span id="l_area_1_5" style="display: inline; ">

    ...some html inputs and stuff....

    </span>
```

Which I am certain by Inspect Element of the Chrome.

Now when I try to address to it programaticly with this:

```
document.getElementById("1_area_1_5").style.display = 'none';
```

I get the `Cannot read property 'style' of null` error.

I have no idea what the hell that's supposed to mean, any help?

Comment: maybe, The problem is that you are calling the javascript function before loading the actual HTML content..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error means that the element doesn't exist. It's because you have a  typo. You wrote `1` instead of `l`.

```
l_area_1_5
1_area_1_5
^
```

Comment: @eric.itzhak, The font `Courier New` `1` looks exactly the same as `l`, i was having a crack at you