# Resolve the error: Cannot read property 'style' of null" with a better approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a common `js` file for 2 different pages. In **Page 1**, I just want to show the `text2` field when the `LName` input has any value. Otherwise, I want it to be hidden. So I created an `if` condition to see whether there is any value for the `LName` input and if there is no value, I kept the `display: none;`.

In **Page 2**, I don't need the div for `id="text2"`, so dropped it. As a result, whenever I give an input, it returns an error as there is no div with `id="text2"`.

I need a single `js` file, at the same time, I need to show the `text2` div in Page 1 but I don't want to keep the `<div id="text2" class="display: none;"></div>` in the Page 2 as I don't need it there. How can I solve this problem? Is there any better approach I could take?

This is the working Page 1 in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/aq9Laaew/10099/).

And this is the Page 2 in the snippet, that returns an error:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup change", "#FName, #LName", function() {
    var FName = $('#FName').val();
    var LName = $('#LName').val();

    var listP = document.getElementById('list');
    if ($('#FName').val() == "") {
      listP.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      listP.style.display = 'block';
    }

    var text2P = document.getElementById('text2');
    if ($('#LName').val() == "") {
      text2P.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      text2P.style.display = 'block';
    }

    $('#text1').html('<li>This is text 1</li>');
    $('#text2').html('<li>This is text 2</li>');
    $('#text3').html('<li>This is text 3</li>');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FName: <input name="FName" id="FName"><br> LName: <input name="LName" id="LName"><br>
<div id="list">
  <div id="text1"></div>
  <div id="text3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncomment the text2 field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'style' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113729/cannot-read-property-style-of-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `text2P` is not falsy:

```
var text2P = document.getElementById('text2');
if (text2P) {
    if ($('#LName').val() == "") {
        text2P.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        text2P.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

### Doc

[MDN web docs: Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I don't want to keep the `<div id="text2" class="display: none;"></div>` in the Page 2 as I don't need it there. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, with the code I have wrote in the answer you don't need the `<div>` in the html.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the lesson. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as solved if it's the case ^_^.